# How to get the value and id from a drop down in php?

Tags: php, html

I have created and html form which have a drop down list.

This drop down list is populated from database.

```
<select name="classes">
<?php
foreach() {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $name ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Now I want to get the $id and $name both. How will I do this?

I have tried this

```
echo $_POST['classes'];
```

But it only displays the $id of the select item. And I want $id and $name both.

Comment: Only the ID of the selected option gets POSTed. The point is that the ID serves as an alias to the name, thus knowing the ID should be enough for you to know the name.

Comment: I you need both, you'll have to use JavaScript to change the post request.

Comment: but I need both. How will get both id and name? Is it possible in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. One possibility would be placing both infos inside the `value` attribute, and then separating them back again with php (by using a delimiter):

```
<option value="<?php echo $id.'|'.$name; ?>"><?php echo $name ?></option>
```

In PHP:

```
$datas = explode('|',$_POST['classes']);
$id = $datas[0];
$name = $datas[1];
```

But that's not how the system is meant to be. Usually the $name would be used only as a "friendly" info for the user, cause the value might sometimes just be an INT and user won't understand what that int refers to, so we give him a word description in order to choose an option: but what you would only care of is that value indeed, which you can always use to get again the description that comes along with it (by a search to the database, for ex.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, when you submit that form, only the value is going to be carried over. If there is no value then the inner HTML becomes the value.

What I'd do is:

```
<select name="classes">
<?php  
foreach($classes as $id => $name) //i'm guessing here, is this what you meant? 
 {  ?>  
<option value="<?php echo $id.'|'.$name ?>"><?php echo $name ?></option>
<?php  }  ?>  
</select>
```

In case you are not familiar, the period is the concatenation operator. Think of it as glue for pieces of a string. So I'm gluing $id to the left of "pipe" and then gluing $name onto the end of that.
Then in your handler, use split or explode to separate the two values on the pipe.

Actually, I'd do it a little different, echoing more and going in and out of php/html less, but I tried to leave your code intact as much as possible.

Comment: I'm too slow. Someone else posted just about the same answer as me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

append name to Id and pass it as value,,and explode name from the other end

Answer (score 1):

You want is and name both so while storing option value ,
put like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $id."_".$name;?>"><?php echo $name?></option>
```

and on posting data just explode the value you will get both is and name

Answer (score 0):

Sending form means only sending 'value' for select field (treat 'name' in option as a label only). You can simply fetch 'name' from database when you have 'id' while handling form submission.